# Best hashing method for PK in GCP Spanner

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I have unique strings that I want to use as the `id` column(Primary Key) for a Spanner table. In order to better spread the writes across logical shards, I want to hash the strings as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/schema-design#fix_hash_the_key).

Currently, I'm using sha256 w/hex encoding.

1. Is there a preferred method for hashing strings to use as a Primary Key?
2. In Spanner, are there any drawbacks to using base64 encoding over hex?
3. If the `id` column is `STRING 64`, does the value being smaller than 64 offer any performance benefits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `Is there a preferred method for hashing strings to use as a Primary Key?`

No. Any hash function that evenly distributes the keys will work.

- `In Spanner, are there any drawbacks to using base64 encoding over hex?`

Not in Spanner. They are essentially different ways of representing a byte array. In general, base64 encoded strings may be shorter than the hex (base16) ones; while the hex ones may be more human readable. When it comes to your use case, you probably need to conduct a benchmark and look at the actual performance when weighing up the pros/cons.

- `If the id column is STRING 64, does the value being smaller than 64 offer any performance benefits?`

Technically yes, but it is just because you are storing/fetching less data. `STRING 64` only tells Spanner what the size limit for the key is. It still only allocates the actual space for the key.

In reality it is hard to tell how much benefit you will get as there may be other factors that may out-weigh this tiny benefit. Again, if you are pushing the performance to the limit, you should conduct a benchmark.